# Pulling docker image from GCP gcr in bitbucket pipeline

Tags: bitbucket-pipelines

I have a bitbucket pipeline like this:

```
 definitions:
    steps:
      - step: &step1
          name: step1
          image: eu.gcr.io/$PROJECT/my_private_image:tag
          script:
            - ...
```

And I want to pull "my_private_image:tag" from my Google private gcr or artifact registry, Any help?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Just Read the [Fine Manual](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/use-docker-images-as-build-environments-in-bitbucket-pipelines-792298897.html#UseDockerimagesasbuildenvironments-PrivateimageshostedbyGoogleContainerRegistry(GCR))

> To pull an image from GCR, you need to configure a service account for Pipelines with "Viewer" access in your GCP admin console. Download the generated JSON private key, and copy/paste it into a secure variable in Pipelines. The configured variable can then be used directly in the password field in your YAML image configuration [...]

```
 definitions:
    steps:
      - step: &step1
          name: step1
          image:
            name: eu.gcr.io/$PROJECT/my_private_image:tag
            username: _json_key
            password: '$GCR_JSON_KEY'
          script:
            - ...
```